# C# unit tests get stuck on COM objects

Tags: c#, unit-testing, com

I am working on a project in C# and i have a piece of cod that work perfectly in `main()` but in tests the debugger get stuck on a COM object call and test can't pass that line.

This is the code:

```
    private ICMSDWorkset CMSWorkset;
    private ICMSDProject CMSProject;
    [TestMethod()]
    public void CMSConnector_EntityProviderTest()
    {
        string connectionString = @"PATH";

        CMSAPI capi = new CMSAPI();
        //capi.Init(connectionString, "USER", "Project name");
        Init(connectionString, "@SETUP", "iDB_P01");

        Terminate();
    }
    private void Init(String connectionString, string currentUser, string currentProject)
    {
        CMSWorkset = new CPLTWorkset() as ICMSDWorkset;

        CMSWorkset.Init("", "", connectionString);

        if (!CMSWorkset.IsInitialized())
            throw new ArgumentException(
                new StringBuilder().AppendFormat("")
                    .AppendFormat("initialization failed for connection string '{0}'", connectionString)
                    .ToString()
            );

        // set user
        ICMSDOwnCollection tmpColl = CMSWorkset.GetAllUsers() as ICMSDOwnCollection;
        CMSWorkset.SetCurrentUser(tmpColl.Item(currentUser));

        // set project as current in workset
        tmpColl = CMSWorkset.GetAllProjects() as ICMSDOwnCollection;
        CMSProject = tmpColl.Item(currentProject) as ICMSDProject;
        CMSWorkset.SetCurrentProject(CMSProject);

        if (!CMSWorkset.IsInitialized())
            throw new ArgumentException(
                new StringBuilder().AppendFormat("")
                    .AppendFormat("initialization failed for connection string '{0}', user '{1}' and project name '{2}'",
                        connectionString, currentUser, currentProject)
                    .ToString()
            );
    }

    public void Terminate()
    {
        // do the deallocations; mandatory
        CMSWorkset.Terminate();
        CMSWorkset = null;
    }
```

On test debugging when i press step forward and reach this line :

```
CMSWorkset = new CPLTWorkset() as ICMSDWorkset;
```

the debugger stop working, the test continue running but remains stuck on that line .No errors or exceptions are throw .

`CPLTWorkset` is a wrapper for a COM object.

I checked 'Native code debugging' as other mentions on questions related to COM objects but without success.

Did anyone have any idea why debugger can't handle that line ? or why that piece of cod work on main but not on tests ?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would an supposed isolated unit test have need to interact with COM?

Comment: As Nkosi says above. By definition this isn't a unit test if you are using COM. I would suggest you either mock out the COM call or take a different approach altogether.

Comment: Nothing to do with the debugger or fish, deadlock is not unusual when using COM servers that were not designed to be thread-safe.  The question does not have enough details about the test runner, get ahead by googling "c# mstest apartment state" to find relevant solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first guess is that the code invoked by `new CPLTWorkset()` only works on a thread that is marked as a [`[STAThread]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stathreadattribute(v=vs.110).aspx). Your Main method has this attribute, making the  main thread a single threaded apartment thread, while the threads used by your unit testing framework are not.

Note that just calling [Thread.SetAparatmentState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.setapartmentstate(v=vs.110).aspx) may not fix this; when a thread is an STA thread, this also implies that an event loop is being pumped on it (e.g. in WinForms, [Application.Run](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.run(v=vs.110).aspx) would be called). That is going to be difficult to achieve in a unit test unless you really know what you are doing.

Comment: you are right. After some research i solved the problem by running them in NUnit console because there i can set my tests to run on a single thread,but your answer helped me to find this solution ... so i will mark it as correct . Thanks !